# Azure B2C freezing on mobile device

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have this exact same issue with Azure B2C pages. After email verification the application freezes and the user isn't able to continue setting up their account.

I saw this post in microsoft but there seems to be no answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/174649/azure-ad-b2c-signup-page-freezing-after-email-veri.html

The issue can't be replicated on a normal browser, but once we integrate b2c with a mobile app the issue happens.

Comment: Thanks and could you please follow the document mentioned below and let us know if issue still persist. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication).

Comment: we're using email login.